# Exception android.view.inflate exception

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I woudlike to programe a 8 listchoose fragment with 2 two spinners and 2 text input and textview but i get inflate exception i make it from android tutorial

This is main class:

```
import com.calculator.mycalculator.R;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;



public class EnotaMainHendler extends FragmentActivity 
implements HeadlinesFragment.OnHeadlineSelectedListener {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.news_articles);

// Check whether the activity is using the layout version with
// the fragment_container FrameLayout. If so, we must add the first fragment
if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {

    // However, if we're being restored from a previous state,
    // then we don't need to do anything and should return or else
    // we could end up with overlapping fragments.
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        return;
    }

    // Create an instance of ExampleFragment
    HeadlinesFragment firstFragment = new HeadlinesFragment();

    // In case this activity was started with special instructions from an Intent,
    // pass the Intent's extras to the fragment as arguments
    firstFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

    // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit();
}
}

public void onArticleSelected(int position) {
// The user selected the headline of an article from the HeadlinesFragment

// Capture the article fragment from the activity layout
ArticleFragment articleFrag = (ArticleFragment)
        getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.article_fragment);

if (articleFrag != null) {
    // If article frag is available, we're in two-pane layout...

    // Call a method in the ArticleFragment to update its content
    articleFrag.updateArticleView(position);

} else {
    // If the frag is not available, we're in the one-pane layout and must swap frags...

    // Create fragment and give it an argument for the selected article
    ArticleFragment newFragment = new ArticleFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ArticleFragment.ARG_POSITION, position);
    newFragment.setArguments(args);
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
    // and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);

    // Commit the transaction
    transaction.commit();
}
}
}
```

this is fragment class:

```
    package com.Converter.myConverter.Unit;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import com.calculator.mycalculator.R;
    import com.google.android.gms.wearable.NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult;

    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.text.Editable;
    import android.text.TextWatcher;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Spinner;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class ArticleFragment extends Fragment
    implements
    OnItemSelectedListener, TextWatcher, OnClickListener{
        final static String ARG_POSITION = "position";
        int mCurrentPosition = -1;

        //notri so zapisane vse enote
        private ArrayList<Enota> enote;
        private ArrayList<String>   e;
        private ArrayAdapter enoteAdapter;

        // Spiner za vhodne podatke
        private Spinner inputSpinner;

        // Spinner za izhodne podatke
        private Spinner outputSpinner;

        private double inputAmount;
        private boolean inputValid;


    //indeksa ki povesta katera je trenutna stvar izbrana
        private int unitInputIndex1;
        private int unitInputIndex2;

        //normalizirana mera ki je trenutno prikazana
        private double inputRate1;
        private double inputRate2;

        // rabimo tudi ime kot so moÄŤ, kot itd..
        String category;

    /// Context context;
      /*  
        String[] values = new String[] { getString(R.string.angleP), 
                getString(R.string.surface), 
                getString(R.string.energy),
                getString(R.string.angleP),
                getString(R.string.lenght),
                getString(R.string.mass),
                getString(R.string.pressure),
                getString(R.string.speed),
                getString(R.string.temperature),
                getString(R.string.time),
                getString(R.string.volume),

        };
    */


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {



            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                mCurrentPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(ARG_POSITION);
            }
            View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, container, false);

            e=new ArrayList<String>();
            //dobime ime kategorije
         //   this.category = getIntent().getStringExtra("category");
            // dobimo enoto

            this.enote = EnoteUpravljalec.getUnits(this.category, getView().getContext(), 1);
            String[] unitNames = new String[this.enote.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < this.enote.size(); i++)
                unitNames[i] = enote.get(i).getLocalizedName();
            enoteAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getView().getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, unitNames);
            enoteAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);



            inputSpinner = (Spinner) getView().findViewById(R.id.unitInput1);
            outputSpinner = (Spinner) getView().findViewById(R.id.unitInput2);
            inputSpinner.setAdapter(enoteAdapter);
            outputSpinner.setAdapter(enoteAdapter);
            inputSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
            outputSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);



            EditText edit_text = (EditText)getView().findViewById(R.id.enotaVrednost);
            edit_text.addTextChangedListener(this);
            this.inputValid = false;

            setConversionOutput("");


            this.unitInputIndex1 = -1;
            this.unitInputIndex2 = -1;
            this.inputRate1 = -1.0;
            this.inputRate2 = -1.0;
            // If activity recreated (such as from screen rotate), restore
            // the previous article selection set by onSaveInstanceState().
            // This is primarily necessary when in the two-pane layout.


            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            return view;
        }



        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();

            // During startup, check if there are arguments passed to the fragment.
            // onStart is a good place to do this because the layout has already been
            // applied to the fragment at this point so we can safely call the method
            // below that sets the article text.
            Bundle args = getArguments();
            if (args != null) {
                // Set article based on argument passed in
                updateArticleView(args.getInt(ARG_POSITION));
            } else if (mCurrentPosition != -1) {
                // Set article based on saved instance state defined during onCreateView
                updateArticleView(mCurrentPosition);
            }
        }

        public void updateArticleView(int position) {
          //  TextView article = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.article);
           // article.setText(Ipsum.Articles[position]);
            mCurrentPosition = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

            // Save the current article selection in case we need to recreate the fragment
            outState.putInt(ARG_POSITION, mCurrentPosition);
        }

        private void setConversionOutput(String s) {
            TextView v = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.unit_conversion_output);
            v.setText(s);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable amount) {
            if (amount.length() == 0) {
                // If no text is entered, the input is invalid.
                this.inputValid = false;
            } else {

                String text = amount.toString();
                try {
                    this.inputAmount = Double.parseDouble(text);
                    this.inputValid = true;

                    NarediPretvorbo();
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    this.inputValid = false;

                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        private Enota getUnit(int index)
        {

                return enote.get(index);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                   int position, long id)
        {
            switch (parent.getId()) {
            case R.id.unitInput1:
                // The "from" unit has been changed.
                unitInputIndex1 = position;
                inputRate1 = getUnit(position).getNormalizedValue();
                break;
            case R.id.unitInput2:
                // The "to" unit has been changed.
                unitInputIndex2 = position;
                inputRate2 = getUnit(unitInputIndex2).getNormalizedValue();
                break;
            }

            // If something is selected in both spinners, make a unit conversion.
            NarediPretvorbo();
        }


        public void NarediPretvorbo() {

            if (this.unitInputIndex1 == -1 || this.unitInputIndex2 == -1)
                return;

            double vred;
            if (this.inputValid)
                vred = this.inputAmount;
            else
                vred = 1.0;

            String LokalnaEnota1 = getUnit(unitInputIndex1).getLocalizedName();
            String LokalnaEnota2 = getUnit(unitInputIndex2).getLocalizedName();


            double resultAmount = 0.0;

            if (this.category.equalsIgnoreCase("temperatura")) {

                if (LokalnaEnota1.equalsIgnoreCase(LokalnaEnota2)) {
                    resultAmount = vred;
                } else if (LokalnaEnota1.equalsIgnoreCase("fahrenheit")) {
                    if (LokalnaEnota2.equalsIgnoreCase("celsius")) {
                        resultAmount = (vred - 32) * (5/9.0);
                    } else if (LokalnaEnota2.equalsIgnoreCase("kelvin")) {
                        resultAmount = (vred - 32) * (5/9.0) + 273.15;
                    }
                } else if (LokalnaEnota1.equalsIgnoreCase("celsius")) {
                    if (LokalnaEnota2.equalsIgnoreCase("fahrenheit")) {
                        resultAmount = (vred * (9/5.0)) + 32;
                    } else if (LokalnaEnota2.equalsIgnoreCase("kelvin")) {
                        resultAmount = vred + 273.15;
                    }
                } else if (LokalnaEnota1.equalsIgnoreCase("kelvin")) {
                    if (LokalnaEnota2.equalsIgnoreCase("fahrenheit")) {
                        resultAmount = ((vred - 273.15) * 1.8) + 32;
                    } else if (LokalnaEnota2.equalsIgnoreCase("celsius")) {
                        resultAmount = vred - 273.15;
                    }

                    e.add(category+" "+vred+" "+getUnit(unitInputIndex1).getLocalizedName().toLowerCase()+" "+resultAmount+" "+getUnit(unitInputIndex2).getLocalizedName().toLowerCase());
                }
            } else {
                // Actually make a conversion!
                resultAmount = vred * (this.inputRate1 / this.inputRate2);
                if(vred>1.0&&!this.category.equalsIgnoreCase("temperature"))
                   e.add(category+" iz "+vred+" "+getUnit(unitInputIndex1).getLocalizedName().toLowerCase()+" v "+resultAmount+" "+getUnit(unitInputIndex2).getLocalizedName().toLowerCase());
            }

            // Set the result of the conversion.
            String result = Double.toString(resultAmount);
            setConversionOutput(result);
        }


        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            switch (parent.getId()) {
            case R.id.unitInput1:
                this.unitInputIndex1 = -1;
                this.inputRate1 = -1.0;
                break;
            case R.id.unitInput2:
                this.unitInputIndex2 = -1;
                this.inputRate2 = -1.0;
                break;
            }
        }

    /*
        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
            SaveAllObjects();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            super.onStop();    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
         //  SaveAllObjects();
        }

        //Shranimo podatke v paint4fun file in notri v file txt o zadnji uprabi
        public void SaveAllObjects() {

            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("sez.txt", MODE_APPEND);
                BufferedOutputStream buf = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
                OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(buf);
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(osw);

                writer.newLine();
                if(e.size()>0)
                for (String line :e) //preberemo vse objekte string po string
                    writer.write(line+"\n");


                writer.flush();
                writer.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }






    }
    */    
    }
```

this is listfragment class:

```
  public class HeadlinesFragment extends ListFragment {
        OnHeadlineSelectedListener mCallback;
      /*  String[] values = new String[] { getString(R.string.angleP), 
                getString(R.string.surface), 
                getString(R.string.energy),
                getString(R.string.angleP),
                getString(R.string.lenght),
                getString(R.string.mass),
                getString(R.string.pressure),
                getString(R.string.speed),
                getString(R.string.temperature),
                getString(R.string.time),
                getString(R.string.volume),

        };
    */
        // The container Activity must implement this interface so the frag can deliver messages
        public interface OnHeadlineSelectedListener {
            /** Called by HeadlinesFragment when a list item is selected */
            public void onArticleSelected(int position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // We need to use a different list item layout for devices older than Honeycomb
            int layout = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ?
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1 : android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;

            // Create an array adapter for the list view, using the Ipsum headlines array
            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), layout, Ipsum.Headlines));
        }

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();

            // When in two-pane layout, set the listview to highlight the selected list item
            // (We do this during onStart because at the point the listview is available.)
            if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.article_fragment) != null) {
                getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);

            // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
            // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception.
            try {
                mCallback = (OnHeadlineSelectedListener) activity;
            } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                        + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            // Notify the parent activity of selected item
            mCallback.onArticleSelected(position);

            // Set the item as checked to be highlighted when in two-pane layout
            getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
        }
    }
```

and there is articleview:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"


      >

    <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/scrollView">

            <LinearLayout 
                          android:orientation="vertical"
                          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                          android:layout_height="fill_parent"


                         >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="24dp"

       android:text="@+string/from_currency_amount_label"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/currency_converter_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:inputType="number|numberSigned|numberDecimal" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

     android:text="@+string/from_currency_label"
     android:textSize="20sp"
     android:layout_gravity="left"
     />
 <Spinner
     android:id="@+id/from_currency_spinner"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"

     android:paddingLeft="12dp"
     />

 <TextView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"

     android:text="@+string/to_currency_label"
     android:textSize="20sp"
     android:layout_gravity="left"
     />

 <Spinner
     android:id="@+id/to_currency_spinner"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"


     android:paddingLeft="12dp"
     />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/currency_conversion_output"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"

     android:text=""
     android:textSize="25sp"
     android:padding="12dp"
     android:paddingBottom="12dp"/>


                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/last_updated"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                        android:text=""
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:padding="12dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="12dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>



</LinearLayout>
```

and news article

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

and new article in large:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment android:name="com.Converter.myConverter.Unit.HeadlinesFragment"
              android:id="@+id/headlines_fragment"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <fragment android:name="com.Converter.myConverter.Unit.ArticleFragment"
              android:id="@+id/article_fragment"
              android:layout_weight="2"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

but i get exception i am very sad:

```
08-24 10:13:24.891: E/AndroidRuntime(22932): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-24 10:13:24.891: E/AndroidRuntime(22932): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.calculator.mycalculator/com.Converter.myConverter.Unit.EnotaMainHendler}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class fragment
08-24 10:13:24.891: E/AndroidRuntime(22932):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
08-24 10:13:24.891: E/AndroidRuntime(22932):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
08-24 10:13:24.891: E/AndroidRuntime(22932):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-24 10:13:24.891: E/AndroidRuntime(22932):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
08-24 10:13:24.891: E/AndroidRuntime(22932):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-24 10:13:24.891: E/AndroidRuntime(22932):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-24 10:13:24.891: E/AndroidRuntime(22932):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-24 10:13:24.891: E/AndroidRuntime(22932):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-24 10:13:24.891: E/AndroidRuntime(22932):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-24 10:13:24.891: E/AndroidRuntime(22932):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-24 10:13:24.891: E/AndroidRuntime(22932):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-24 10:13:24.891: E/AndroidRuntime(22932):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-24 10:13:24.891: E/AndroidRuntime(22932): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class fragment
08-24 10:13:24.891: E/AndroidRuntime(22932):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
08-24 10:13:24.891: E/AndroidRuntime(22932):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
08-24 10:13:24.891: E/AndroidRuntime(22932):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
08-24 10:13:24.891: E/AndroidRuntime(22932):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
08-24 10:13:24.891: E/AndroidRuntime(22932):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
08-24 10:13:24.891: E/AndroidRuntime(22932):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
08-24 10:13:24.891: E/AndroidRuntime(22932):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
08-24 10:13:24.891: E/AndroidRuntime(22932):    at com.Converter.myConverter.Unit.EnotaMainHendler.onCreate(EnotaMainHendler.java:38)
08-24 10:13:24.891: E/AndroidRuntime(22932):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
08-24 10:13:24.891: E/AndroidRuntime(22932):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
08-24 10:13:24.891: E/AndroidRuntime(22932):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
08-24 10:13:24.891: E/AndroidRuntime(22932):    ... 11 more
08-24 10:13:24.891: E/AndroidRuntime(22932): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-24 10:13:24.891: E/AndroidRuntime(22932):    at com.Converter.myConverter.Unit.ArticleFragment.onCreateView(ArticleFragment.java:105)
08-24 10:13:24.891: E/AndroidRuntime(22932):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1504)
08-24 10:13:24.891: E/AndroidRuntime(22932):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:915)
08-24 10:13:24.891: E/AndroidRuntime(22932):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1099)
08-24 10:13:24.891: E/AndroidRuntime(22932):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1201)
08-24 10:13:24.891: E/AndroidRuntime(22932):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:292)
08-24 10:13:24.891: E/AndroidRuntime(22932):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
08-24 10:13:24.891: E/AndroidRuntime(22932):    ... 21 more
```

Comment: What is line 105 of ArticleFragment.java?

Comment: this.enote = EnoteUpravljalec.getUnits(this.category, getView().getContext(), 1);

Comment: it calls other class which convert unit etc: meter to milimeter it work all in activityes but look is ugly in tablet, because i make a decision for fragments

Comment: `getView()` is probably returning `null`. Why are you manually calling `getView()`? Most likely you should simply call `getActivity()` if you need a `Context`.

Comment: yes :) i debug and i find problam damm :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.enote = EnoteUpravljalec.getUnits(this.category, getView().getContext(), 1);
```

`getView()` is probably returning `null` here.

Also, it is incorrect to call `getVew()` manually like this. Instead, you should use `getActivity()`:

```
this.enote = EnoteUpravljalec.getUnits(this.category, getActivity(), 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your imports in `EnotaMainHendler` from:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.ListFragment;
```

to:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
```

Also you may want to use `class` attribute instead of `name`:

```
<fragment android:class="com.Converter.myConverter.Unit.HeadlinesFragment"
          android:id="@+id/headlines_fragment"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<fragment android:class="com.Converter.myConverter.Unit.ArticleFragment"
          android:id="@+id/article_fragment"
          android:layout_weight="2"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: hmm if i add import it will be error and class in fragment isnt exist

Comment: @DijaskaskupnostSGV You definitely don't want to mix native Fragments with the support FragmentManager.